# How do I get the path of where my file is?

Tags: php

`domain.com/hello/world/`

How do I only get the `/hello/world/` part?

Update: How could I get `domain.com/hello/world`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

Comment: @Doug name can be easily cut out

Comment: @Doug If you don't want the file name you should probably edit the question to say that; the "path" of a file includes the name itself

Answer (score 1):

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is the actual uri in the browser.

Comment: This will get all GET params too, if that's what you want.

Comment: @alex it can be easily cut out, while it's the only way to get actual request. E.g. if mod_rewrite being used.